# different users, one access web database, permissions

Tags: permissions, database, access

I want to create a Sharepoint site and want to publish an Access web database on it. I want to know is there a way to give different permissions to Sharepoint site users? Some users have just read permissions, some have just add permissions and some have edit permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you're talking about Access Services service application; yes, you can manage permissions using the default SharePoint mechanism. See http://www.mattjimison.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Access-Services.pdf for a pretty good overview of features.

Comment: Actually I want to have a database that there are some objects which some of them are visible to every user and some of them are not visible for all but for just the administrator.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that. Just create a quick proof of concept to see if everything you need is there. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-integrating-data-between-access-and-a-sharepoint-site-HA010131463.aspx